# sorting a mongodb by week and then suming data and avreging it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to sort a mongodb collection by week and then summing data and averaging it.

All my documents are identical:

```
{
    "flight_date": {
        "$date": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "flight_number": 20,
    "origin_city": "San Francisco, CA",
    "destination_city": "New York, NY",
    "delay_in_minutes": 6,
    "cancelled": 0
}
```

so far my best attempt looks like this

```js
db.flightStats.aggregate([
    {
        $group: { _id: { $week: "$flight_date" } },
        $group: {
            _id: { delay_in_minutes: "$delay_in_minutes" },
            total_delay: { $sum: 1 },
            avgDelay: { $avg: "$delay_in_minutes" }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { avgDelay: -1 } }

]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1):

So the query is grouping the data by week number and then calculating the sum and average of `delay_in_minutes` field and then sorting it in descending order of `avgDelay`.

Try this:

```js
db.flightStats.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $week: "$flight_date" },
            total_delay: { $sum: "$delay_in_minutes" },
            avgDelay: { $avg: "$delay_in_minutes" }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { avgDelay: -1 } }
]);
```

Update based on comment:

```js
db.flightStats.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $week: "$flight_date" },
            total_delay: { $sum: "$delay_in_minutes" },
            avgDelay: { $avg: "$delay_in_minutes" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            _id: 5 // Week number 5 for example
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: thanks! works like a charm!. any chance you know how can i access a specific week? the results in mongo shell are given by a numbered id per week and i need to access a specific week

Comment: Check the updated answer. If you want a specific week then no need to sort the query.

Comment: Note `$weeks` returns week which begin on Sundays, and week 1 begins with the first Sunday of the year. Days preceding the first Sunday of the year are in week 0. You may check `$isoWeek` If your data spans more than one year, then you should also group by `$year` (or `$isoWeekYear`)